# Build An App With Intel's XDA, But Need Hardware Access Like PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, appframework

I'm totally new in PhoneGap and AppFramework area, that's why I need your opinion about what I'm thinking about these two.

I was testing PhoneGap demo code on my Android tablet and I can see that the HTML code can access almost all hardware feature I need. Such as GeoLocation, Camera, etc.

But when I need something relates with UI, AppFramework give me best result compare to jQuery Mobile. It has smooth transitions from page to page, It has no problem with scrolling too. I love AppFramework.

Now, here comes the problem...

Yesterday, I just read that AppFramework *actually* have native app builder itself. Called AppMobi. Also, I discovered that Intel have PushMobi for push notification service. It's seems that all Intel has is perfect.

However... I just notice that I don't see that Intel's stuff have access to hardware just like PhoneGap has. For example : Camera or GeoLocation (GPS).

Is it really doesn't have that feature or just me who doesn't know yet?

that's all I need to know... thanks.